# PHP curl: CURLOPT_URL, CURLOPT_POST, and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, post, curl, get

If I have a URL that looks like this:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/?foo=bar';
```

And then execute curl as follows:

```
$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
```

I understand that I make this request via GET (default).

Now if I set the following option in the same scenario:

```
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

I understand it uses POST instead of GET, but does it then POST `foo` with a value of `bar`? Or would the proper way for that be:

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/';
$post = 'foo=bar';
$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
```

And what happens if I do this (i.e. submit the value in the URL and via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS):

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/?foo=bar';
$post = 'foo=bar';
$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($resource);
curl_close($resource);
```

How will the data be submitted in that scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between POST and GET is how the server retrieves the data.  As you have set CURLOPT_POST to true, the server normally receives the parameters via the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS value (i.e. the parameters in the HTTP body) and presumably ignore the parameters sent in the URL string - but that really depends on the individual server.

Comment: I'm using a company's REST API and they ask that I POST the username and password to retrieve a token. If I POST to their generic URL with my values set only in `$post`, it fails. If I keep the values in the URL and don't set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS but still set CURLOPT_POST to 1, then it succeeds, and that doesn't make any sense to me. So is it possible that their REST API is flawed?

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense to me either, what happens if you send it as a GET request but add HTTP header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'?

Comment: If I use GET, even with that header, I get an application specific error that says GET is not supported.

Comment: Well, it seems like intended functioning, the company are obviously free to implement their API how they wish.  So they want you to send a POST request with the parameters sent in the URL rather than payload.

Comment: If, however, you are sending a POST with no actual POST data, but all the data via the URL, what does that provide the company and how is that different then using GET?

Comment: The HTTP request is formed differently, it would be sent as 'POST ?foo=bar HTTP/1.1 /n host: domain.com/'. Note the POST, rather than GET.

Comment: Other than the header formation, does this method provide a benefit i.e. why would a company choose to do that? And is this method unconventional?

Comment: What would be the difference between `curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` and `curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);` which one is good?